# Is it right to look at this query as the count of elements in an intersection?

Tags: sql, postgresql

A bit new to SQL and I have a Postgresql query and it's my understanding in Postgres 9.x that JOIN by default is INNER JOIN:

```
select count(*)
from physical_promotions
JOIN subscriptions ON physical_promotions.product_id = subscriptions.id
JOIN users on subscriptions.user_id = users.id
JOIN referrals ON referrals.referred_user_id = users.id
where physical_promotions.coupon_id = '55';
```

Is the right way to interpret this as the count of all physical promotions with a coupon_id of 55 intersected with a corresponding subscription intersected with a corresponding referral intersected with a corresponding user?

EDIT:

Also, I'm trying to count the number of physical_promotions  - so is that the right way to go about it?

Here is my new query:

```
select count(distinct physical_promotions.id)
    from physical_promotions
    JOIN subscriptions ON physical_promotions.product_id = subscriptions.id
    JOIN users on subscriptions.user_id = users.id
    JOIN referrals ON referrals.referred_user_id = users.id
    where physical_promotions.coupon_id = '55';
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact, you may also write the same thing as follows:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM physical_promotions,
    subscriptions,
    users,
    referrals
WHERE physical_promotions.product_id = subscriptions.id
    AND subscriptions.user_id = users.id
    AND referrals.referred_user_id = users.id
    AND physical_promotions.coupon_id = 55
```

For clarity I would probably recommend explicitly specifying the JOIN type.

Also note that you may not necessarily get a count of unique promotions. For example, if there are 2 subscriptions for one promotion, your results will include that promotion (and user and referral) twice.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to count the number of users that resulted from that promotion - so is that the right way to go about it?

Comment: Really, I'm trying to count the number of subscribed users or actual promotions that resulted in a subscription

Comment: Well I don't know your business logic, but it seems like you're looking for `count(distinct users.id)`.

If you execute your query without ``count()``, you can have a look at the results and tweak it from there. You may also be interested in [grouping](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY).

Comment: I was also trying to count the total number of physical_promotions in that intersection as well.  So based on your answer above, my approach sounds right...One thing - your query gives a completely different result than mine in the question...